# ReactNative Context returns undefined when trying to access a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to use the values/functions from my context but every time I console.log a value that Coes from context the value is undefined.

This is my Context:

```
import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import React, {createContext, FC, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import {fbInit, setNewUserFireStore, subscribeUserFS } from '../services/FirebaseServices';

const initialState = {
    signedIn: false,
  }

export const FirebaseContext = createContext();

export const FirebaseContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [isUserSignedIn, setIsUserSignedIn] = useState(initialState.signedIn);

    useEffect(() => {
        fbInit();
    })

    const testLog = () => {
        console.log("TAG Test Log Func")
    }

    return (
        <FirebaseContext.Provider value={{isUserSignedIn, setIsUserSignedIn}}>
            {children}
        </FirebaseContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

This is where I am trying to use the values (I am trying to log the values when I press the Button)

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {Button, Card, TextInput} from 'react-native-paper';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../../context/FirebaseContext';
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const initialUserState = {
    userName: 'Nicole Lopez',
    password: '1001008888',
}

export default function LoginScreen() {
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [userState, setUserState] = useState(initialUserState);
    const { fbContext } = useContext(FirebaseContext);
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const onInputChange = (field, value) => {
        setUserState({
            ...userState,
            [field]: value
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setDisabled(userState.userName.length === 0 || userState.password.length === 0);
    }, [userState.userName, userState.password])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <Card style={styles.card}>

                <TextInput
                    mode="outlined"
                    label="Förnamn & Efternman"
                    defaultValue={userState.userName}
                    onChangeText={text => onInputChange("username", text)}
                    right={<TextInput.Icon name="account" onPress={() => {
                    }}/>}
                    style={styles.textInput}/>

                <TextInput
                    mode="outlined"
                    label="Anställningsnummer 100100xxxx"
                    defaultValue={userState.password}
                    right={<TextInput.Icon name="lock"/>}
                    onChangeText={text => onInputChange("password", text)}
                    style={styles.textInput}/>
            </Card>

            <View style={styles.buttonRow}>

                <Button
                    color={disabled ? "gray" : undefined}
                    disabled={disabled}
                    mode={'contained'}
                    icon={'login'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        console.log("TAG isUserSignedIn: " + fbContext?.isuserSignedIn)
                        //fbContext?.testLog()
                        //console.log("TAG LOGIN BTN PRESSED")
                        //navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
                    }}>Login</Button>
            </View>
        </View>
  );
}
```

This is my App.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {StackScreens} from './src/helpers/types';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen/HomeScreen';
import {doc, getFirestore, onSnapshot, setDoc, Unsubscribe as UnsubscribeFS} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { FirebaseContextProvider, FirebaseContext } from './src/context/FirebaseContext';
import { useContext } from 'react';
//import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

//const userDocument = firestore().collection("users").doc('Cstl3bA9xwwH3UwHZJhA').get();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <FirebaseContextProvider>
      <Content />
    </FirebaseContextProvider>
  );
}

export const Content = () => {

  const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef();
  const firebaseContext = useContext({FirebaseContext});

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="LoginScreen">
          <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={HomeScreen} /> 
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Don't know what I have missed, I have installed the packages, I have tried to log different values but all seem to be undefined :/

Comment: Add an empty array to your useEffect for the dependency array - you are firing the fbInit every time state changes.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't do any difference :/

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is undefined because you're trying to destructure the context value, maybe

```
 const { fbContext } = useContext(FirebaseContext);
```

should be

```
 const fbContext = useContext(FirebaseContext);
```

Comment: I Changed it and it docent work and the only answers I find online is that its rendering wrong, but my code looks identical to other codes online that do work :/

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(fbContext)` in the button code? is it undefined?

Comment: This is what I get when I do console.log(fbContext): {isUserSignedIn: false, setIsUserSignedIn: ƒ}
isUserSignedIn: false
setIsUserSignedIn: ƒ ()
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: `{isUserSignedIn: false, setIsUserSignedIn: ƒ}
isUserSignedIn: false
setIsUserSignedIn: ƒ ()
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: So it is working, those are the expected values correct? maybe the problem is in another part. what exactly is the problem now?

Comment: I think the values are working as they are supposed to, my issue is in the second file/code that I posted on my question. I am trying to console.log a value from my context but the value I get Is undefined. there is some thing that I am missing but I really can't find it.

Comment: If you are talking about this part `console.log("TAG isUserSignedIn: " + fbContext?.isuserSignedIn)`, the "u" from isUserSignedIn is lowercase when it should be uppercase, like this `fbContext?.isUserSignedIn`. I personally recommend using TypeScript, as it avoids this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

For someone getting undefined from context, check on which level you placed your context provider. If you want to use context in a component you should wrap this component in a context provider outside of this component!

Incorrect way

```js
const Component = () => {
  const { value1, value2 } = useContext(MyContext); //here context value will be undefined

return (
  <ContextProvider>
      //Component content
  </ContextProvider>
)
  
}
```

Correct way

```js
const ComponentA = () => {
  const { value1, value2 } = useContext(MyContext);
  
  return(//Component A content)
 
}


const ComponentB = () => {
  return(
   <ContextProvider>
      <ComponentA/>
    </ContextProvider>
  )
}
```